# Form with style

Tags: atk4

I'm using version 4.1.4

Is it possible to create a form having some fields with a background color ?

something like the next image.
[image: example form]

Thanks
Alejandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to put an easy answer to this one. This works with 4.1 too.

```
$form->getElement('yourfield')
    ->js(true)
    ->closest('.atk-form-row-line')
    ->css(array('background'=>'red'));
```

Of course there are many ways and styling of the forms is described here:

- http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/form/styling
- http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/gui/formstyle

Comment: Romans, thanks for your response. I've added that code but The background of the field doesn't change. If i inspect the source I see this " $.atk4(function(){ $('#sample_project_nuevotrabajo_form_fieldtest').closest('.atk-form-row-line').css({'background':'black'});" . I'm doing something wrong or missing something ? thanks again

Comment: No, that's correct. Oh, right since you are using 4.1 the class name would be different. Use inspector to find out the class. I think the element was `<dt>` or `<dd>` in there. It have been changed to `<div>` in 4.2

Comment: Romans you're right. I've found it $f->getElement('field')->js(true)->closest('.atk-field-line')->css(array('background'=>'#c6c3c3')); Very thanks